# Fixnums as Symbols Warning from collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.86

I'm not really understanding this warning.   I'm getting one warning for each record containted in `@directories` when using `@directories` in a `collection_select`.   I've tried playing around with the `:id` instances using them differently but with no luck.  I'm sure it's something simple (I'm still pretty new).

Thanks in Advance!

error:

> C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:328:
>
> warning: do not use Fixnums as Symbols

The offending code:

```
<% if !params[:directory].nil? %>
  <%= collection_select :directory, :id, @directories, (:id).to_i, :name,
                      {:selected => params[:directory][:id].map{|id|id.to_i}}, {:size => 7, :multiple => true} %>
<% else %>
  <%= collection_select :directory, :id, @directories, (:id).to_i, :name,
                      {:selected => @directory_ids}, {:size => 7, :multiple => true} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does @collections look like? (@collections.inspect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in `(:id).to_i` as an argument to `collection_select`. `collection_select` then uses it as an argument to `send`. Since `(:id).to_i` is an integer and `send` being called with an integer as an argument is almost always a mistake, `send` emits the warning you get.

It should be noted that there is no reason to use `:id.to_i` instead of just `:id` here since the only difference between `send(:symbol)` and `send(:symbol.to_i)` is that the latter produces a warning.

Comment: Yes, that works.  I feel stupid.   I have no idea why I had it that way or thought it needed to be that way.   I was pretty confused when I was trying to get the collection_select to work (first time and all...).   Thank You!